# What's the black warping liquid where the noumus appear from in season 3 episode 9?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In season 3 episode 9 kurogiri was knocked unconscious yet noumus started to appear from a black warping liquid. What's the black warping liquid and who controls it?

Comment: Speaking as someone who's only watched the show up to the same point ... maybe keep watching and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That black warping liquid is a **Quirk** called **Transmission**!

From the [wiki](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Transmission):

> **Transmission** is a stolen Quirk from an unknown person used by [All For One](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/All_For_One)

Also:

> This Quirk can produce a black liquid that acts as a portal, similar in nature to Kurogiri's Warp Gate. Also similar to Warp Gate, this black liquid can also teleport people by engulfing them whole.